# Using Javascript to hide element class based on body text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, display

I have a dynamically generating page that changes content dependent on whether the user is logged in or not.

As such, there are **some elements I would like to hide based on the text in the body** of the webpage.

Example HTML:

```
    <div class="button-wrapper">
         <a class="button-1" href="/upload" id="button-pop">
              <span class="button-text">Upload New Product</span>
         </a>
    </div>
    <div class="wv-signupnotice">
         <h3>Sign up to start learning</h3>
              <p>Help children in rural communities</p>     
    </div>
```

So I want to **hide the class** `.button-wrapper` if the text "rural communities" is found on the webpage, or similarly, if class `.wv-signupnotice` is present.

Here's the Javascript I tried to no avail:

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('button-wrapper');

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    let div = divs[x];
    let content = div.innerHTML.trim();

    if (content == 'rural communities') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. Are you experiencing any errors?

Comment: Nope, no errors I could see, the class `button-wrapper` just won't hide! It's being very stubborn!

Comment: `I want to hide the class button-wrapper if the text "rural communities" is found on the webpage, or similarly, if class wv-signupnotice is present.` If that is really what you want, shouldn't you do that check *outside* of the loop, because it doesn't depend on any individual `.button-wrapper` div? Or do you want logic that depends on checking the content of a `.button-wrapper` somehow?

Comment: Yeah, I don't actually care about what's inside `.button-wrapper`, rather I just want `.button-wrapper` is be hidden if the text "rural communities" is present anywhere on the web page.

Comment: This is dynamically generated though. At any point will there be more than one case of "rural communities" on the page?

Comment: Nope, it'll only be generated in the instance where I want `.button-wrapper` to be hidden

Comment: I see. Somewhat confused about the wording. As currently constructed, the "rural-communities" text only appears in the "ww-signupnotice" class... But you're saying if "ww-signupnotice" appears at all, we should hide it and the other button? In that case we wouldn't even have to check for rural-communities, just check if class "ww-signupnotice" exists.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Andy no worries, do you have the ability to edit the markup of this page like. If you wanted to add additional elements like a "div" could you update the HTML before generation?

Comment: No I cannot change the markup directly

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, much appreciated! Got it to work now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('button-wrapper');

This function will return the collection of elements with button-wrapper class. Follows the code which will hide this div if there is any other div with wv-signupnotice present on the document. Hope it helps.

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('button-wrapper');

$(document).ready(function() {
if($('div').hasClass("wv-signupnotice"))
divs[0].style.display="none";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-wrapper">
         <a class="button-1" href="/upload" id="button-pop">
              <span class="button-text">Upload New Product</span>
         </a>
    </div>
    <div class="wv-signupnotice">
         <h3>Sign up to start learning</h3>
              <p>Help children in rural communities</p>     
    </div>
```

Comment: You can put the js code in ready function as above. are you using jquery? If you see the code it works fine unless you have something else going on your page before. Made the edits.

Answer (score 0):

The innerHTML you are retrieving in your case will never be equal to 'rural communities' as the innerHTML will actually be something like 'a class="...rural communities...span>../a>'

Think you should go for indexOf rather:

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('button-wrapper');

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    let div = divs[x];
    let content = div.innerHTML.trim();

    if (content.indexOf('rural communities') > -1) {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, in any case, for your generous help! It is greatly appreciated!